# in SQL/PHP returning id with the highest and 2nd-5th highest date

Tags: php, sql, max

As said in the title, I need FIVE queries that returns the ID for rows with the 1st-5th most recent date.

Table: film

```
id     releasedate
232143 2013-06-20
536523 2013-07-20
453554 2013-08-20
098776 2013-09-20
549302 2013-10-20
```

i.e the first query would return the id 549302

I think this would work for the first query:

```
$first = $db->query("SELECT id, FROM film WHERE MAX(releasedate)" );
```

PS: Sorry for the poor formatting of this post, can anyone tell me how to display tables appropriately?

I need to display each id at different points on the web page. Simply returning a list of ids won't suffice. What I really need is for each id to be encapsulated into a unique variable so i can call them at different points on the web page.

Comment: Do you need top 5 i.e. recent records?

Comment: No, i need the most recently released films(using the releasedate column)

Comment: Re: formatting. Paste your table in, then use the `{}` tool in the SO editor, or type Ctl-k, to mark it as a code block to be displayed literally.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need five queries.

```
$first = $db->query("SELECT `id` FROM `film` ORDER BY `releasedate` DESC LIMIT 5" );
```

This will get the IDs from the database of the five most recent films in your table.

To access each of these just run through a `while` loop.

```
while($row = $first->fetch_assoc()) {
  $row['id']; # Each ID will be available like this.
}
```

Comment: Okay then i also need a way of separating each ID into different variables

Comment: The thing is I need to display each id at different points on the web page. Simply returning a list of ids won't suffice. What I really need is for each id to be encapsulated into a unique variable so i can call them at different points on the web page.

Comment: @WillDonaghy Save all the results in an array, and then display them at the appropriate places on the page.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to do this in separate queries, you can use the 2-argument form of the `LIMIT` clause, which is `LIMIT offset, count`. To get the newest film, use

```
SELECT id FROM film ORDER BY releasedate DESC LIMIT 0, 1
```

To get the 2nd most recent film, use

```
SELECT id FROM film ORDER BY releasedate DESC LIMIT 1, 1
```

the next one is

```
SELECT id FROM film ORDER BY releasedate DESC LIMIT 2, 1
```

and so on.

But it should be better to get them all in one query with

```
SELECT id FROM film ORDER BY releasedate DESC LIMIT 5
```

You can then save them all in an array with:

```
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $ids[] = $row['id'];
}
```

Then you can use `$ids[0]` to display the most recent film, `$ids[1]` for the second most recent, and so on.